# Reading Path environment variable in Python returns a different value than Windows

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables

I have a non-admin account in Windows. I add a folder to my `PATH` environment variable in Windows using `Control Pane -> User Accounts -> User Accounts -> Change my environment variables`.
I also added the same folder to system's `PATH` variable using an admin account.

Then I tried to read the `PATH` in Python 3.7 using `os.environ`.

```
import os, sys
path_values = os.environ['PATH'].split(';')
```

It shows me a different list of values for `PATH`. It includes folders that I don't see in Windows GUI of environment variables. And **most importantly** it does not include the folder that I added.

Am I missing something?